# How to build a negative lookahead parser in nom?

Tags: rust, nom

How can I create a negative lookahead parser for `nom`?

For example, I'd like to parse "hello", except if it's followed by " world". The equivalent regex would be `hello(?! world)`.

I tried to combine the `cond`, `not` and `peek` parsers

```rs
fn parser(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    cond(peek(not(tag(" world"))(input)), tag("hello"))(input)
}
```

but this doesn't work as `cond` expects the condition as `bool` instead of as `IResult`.

Comment: `not()` is generally something a parser combinator should avoid to use. It kind of the opposite of what a parser combinator is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [terminated()](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/sequence/fn.terminated.html)

```rs
terminated(tag("hello"), not(tag(" world")))
```

Comment: Oh, using `not` directly. Much more simple than I thought! Thanks.